# Load video stream from IP Camera over the internet

Tags: c#, asp.net, aforge

I built a system using ASP.net, C# & Aforge.net to load video stream into an image control, But it can only work in the same network address (Locally loading stream). 
Does anybody know how to load video stream over the internet?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use library c# of vlc  http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=58438

Comment: it's not working over the internet as well, Hassan. I have tested with VLC application by opening the stream with the URL as I am using another network address and IP Camera is in another network address range.